# slideup animation with fadeIn animation to move next form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create animation on button click event to slideup the form then call the next form it also slide up and call the next form but my form disappear after one slideup animation and does not show any forms.
script.js file is.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//Move to next Step
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click',function(){
    $('.registration-form').slideUp('slow',function(){
    var parent_fieldset=$(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text],textarea').each(function(){

    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
        next_step=false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    }

    });
    if(next_step){
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(1000,function()
        {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }

});
});


});
```

style.css

```
body{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#888;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.form-box{
    padding:40px;
}
 .form-bottom{
     padding:25px 25px 30px 25px;
     background:#eee;
     text-align:left;

}
form .form-bottom textarea{
    height:100px;
}
form .form-bottom button.btn{
    min-width: 105px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
form .form-bottom .input-error{
    border-color:#19b9e7
}
form.registration-form fieldset{
    display:none;
}
```

form-element.css

```
input[type="text"],
textarea,
textarea.form-control{
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#888;
    

}
textarea.form-control{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom :10px;
    line-height:30px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus{
    outline: 0;
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid #ccc;
    
}
button.btn{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#334EFF;
    border:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:none;
}
button.btn:focus{
    outline:0;
    opacity:0.6;
    background:#334EFF;
    box-shadow:none;
    color:#fff;
}
button.btn:active:focus,button.btn.active:focus{
    outline:0;
    opacity:0.6;
    background:#334EFF;
    color:#fff;

}
```

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multisteps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-elements.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class ="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                <form role="form" action method="post" class="registration-form">
                    <fieldset style="display:block;">

                        <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First Name---" class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name">
                                    </div><!--End of group div-->
                                    <br>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Get Started</button>
                            
                        </div><!--End of bottom form-->
                        </fieldset><!--End of first form field set-->
                        <fieldset><!--Start 2nd form field set-->
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control" id="form-email">
                                </div><!--End of 2nd form groupdiv-->
                                <br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div><!--End of bottom div-->

                        </fieldset><!--End of second form fieldset-->
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-twitter">Twitter</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-twitter" placeholder="Twitter Account" class="form-twitter form-control" id="form-twitter">
                                </div><!--End of third form group div--><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me Up

                                </button>
                            </div><!--End of third form bottom-->

                        </fieldset><!--third field set End-->


                </form><!--End of Form-->

            </div><!--End of form column div-->
            

        </div><!--End of Row Div-->
    
    </div><!--Container div end-->

<!--
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//Move to next Step
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click',function(){
    var parent_fieldset=$(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text],textarea').each(function(){

    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
        next_step=false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    }

    });
    if(next_step){
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400,function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    }

});


});


</script>

-->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help anyone try to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello, can you validate my answer plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was hidding the form instead of the fielset

forget a double quote there : input[type=**"text]**

With next function, you can set the selector like : .next(**'fieldset'**)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //Move to next Step
  $('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click',function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset'), next_step = true;
    
    $(parent_fieldset).slideUp('slow',function(){
      
      $('input[type="text"],textarea', parent_fieldset).each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "") {
          $(this).addClass('input-error');
          next_step = false;
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }

      });

      if (next_step) {
        $(parent_fieldset).fadeOut(1000,function() {
          $(parent_fieldset).next('fieldset').fadeIn();
        });
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#888;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.form-box{
    padding:40px;
}
 .form-bottom{
     padding:25px 25px 30px 25px;
     background:#eee;
     text-align:left;

}
form .form-bottom textarea{
    height:100px;
}
form .form-bottom button.btn{
    min-width: 105px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
form .form-bottom .input-error{
    border-color:#19b9e7
}
form.registration-form fieldset{
    display:none;
}

form-element.css

input[type="text"],
textarea,
textarea.form-control{
    height:50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#888;
    

}
textarea.form-control{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom :10px;
    line-height:30px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus{
    outline: 0;
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid #ccc;
    
}
button.btn{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#334EFF;
    border:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:none;
}
button.btn:focus{
    outline:0;
    opacity:0.6;
    background:#334EFF;
    box-shadow:none;
    color:#fff;
}
button.btn:active:focus,button.btn.active:focus{
    outline:0;
    opacity:0.6;
    background:#334EFF;
    color:#fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multisteps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-elements.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class ="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                <form role="form" action method="post" class="registration-form">
                    <fieldset style="display:block;">

                        <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First Name---" class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name">
                                    </div><!--End of group div-->
                                    <br>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Get Started</button>
                            
                        </div><!--End of bottom form-->
                        </fieldset><!--End of first form field set-->
                        <fieldset><!--Start 2nd form field set-->
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control" id="form-email">
                                </div><!--End of 2nd form groupdiv-->
                                <br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div><!--End of bottom div-->

                        </fieldset><!--End of second form fieldset-->
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-twitter">Twitter</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-twitter" placeholder="Twitter Account" class="form-twitter form-control" id="form-twitter">
                                </div><!--End of third form group div--><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me Up

                                </button>
                            </div><!--End of third form bottom-->

                        </fieldset><!--third field set End-->


                </form><!--End of Form-->

            </div><!--End of form column div-->
            

        </div><!--End of Row Div-->
    
    </div><!--Container div end-->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please tell me how can I adjust my third form also disappear with slide up .It disappear suddenly